# execute normal command doesn't work

Tags: vimscript, normal-mode

Running `execute g:xx` doesn't work.

```
let g:str="move to right win\t<C-w>h"
let g:temp=escape(matchstr(g:str,'\(\t\)\@<=.*$'),'<')
let g:xx= "normal ".g:temp

execute g:xx
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: hi Herb Wolfe,first there is a mistake above:Move to left. As picture show above,two of three situations work fine(execute command),but execute g:xx is not work

Comment: Can you post the actual file, and not just a screen shot? It's difficult to tell if that's the entire file, and it's easier to copy and paste text for testing.

Comment: sorry,i have posted the test code.

Answer (score 1):

```
let g:temp=eval('"'. g:temp .'"')
```

after

> ```
> let g:temp=escape(matchstr(g:str,'\(\t\)\@<=.*$'),'<')
> ```

---

Extracting this into a `:function`:

```
function! Literalize(string)
    " get already properly escaped sequences out of the way, so we don't double-escape them
    let s = eval('"'. a:string .'"')
    " escape remaining special key sequences
    let s = escape(s, '<')
    let s = eval('"'.   s      .'"')
    return s
endfunction
```

---

#### Explanation

The problem was that `escape()` handles its input° and output [strings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-string) as a literal-string (as in single quotes `''`).  So escaping the `<` in `"<C-w>"` results in `'\<C-w>'`, not the desired `"\<C-w>"`/`'^W'`.

° If the input is given as a double quoted `"string"`, its escape sequences are evaluated by the vimscript parser, before it is passed to `escape()`.

Comment: @tracyone, gladly!  (Note I edited my answer to expand on it.)  If you feel it has answered your question well, please ✔ accept and ↑ upvote it: http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

In your first line, the `<C-w>` is not escaped, so it appears to be matched as a literal string, and the `escape` function doesn't convert it to the ^W character.

So to get what you want, the first line should actually read

```
let g:str="move to right win\t\<C-w>h"
```

In addition, according to the documentation [here at sourceforge](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#escape()), the escape command doesn't work how you appear to think. It's going to escape just the '<' character, which does nothing.

Comment: Is there a vim function can translate this keycode,I mean <c-w> to ^w.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Yes, `eval()` can do that 'with a little help' – see my [answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10916/execute-normal-command-doesnt-work/10920#10920).